# Change ownership of a share drive

Tags: permissions, mount, chmod, chown, shared-folders

I have a windows machine locally connected to my linux machine. There is a shared folder on the windows machine, which I mounted on my linux machine using `sudo mount -t cifs -o username=myuser //xxx.xxx.xx.xx/myfolder /mnt/windowsshare/` and it's mounted successfully and I can see the files and folders.

The problem now is that I'm trying to create a folder inside the mounted share but I can't. I've checked the permissions of the mounted folder and it says

> "You are not the owner, so you cannot change these permissions"

as shown below:

[image]

I've tried running `sudo chmod -R 777 /mnt/windowshare` and `sudo chown -R isa /mnt/windowshare` but it says chmod:

> changing permissions of '/mnt/windowshare/.?00000002202011111110e5(and many other chars)': No such file or directory

then I stop the command using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

Any advice how I can have control access over this folder on my linux machine?

Comment: can you create a file on the share with root ?

Comment: @D'ArcyNader How I can do that?

Comment: use this command `sudo touch /mnt/windowshare/testfilename`

Comment: @D'ArcyNader I just tested and yes, I can create a file on the share with root. But it's read only like everything in the shared folder.

Comment: i'm writing an answer for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to change permissions on a windows share when it's already mounted, but it is possible to change them during the mount.

first unmount your share with:

```
sudo umount /mnt/windowshare/
```

then mount the share again with these new arguments:

```
sudo mount.cifs -o username=myuser,uid=youruser,gid=yourgroup //xxx.xxx.xx.xx/myfolder /mnt/windowsshare/
```

*quoting from the mount.cifs man*

> **uid=arg** sets the uid that will own all files or directories on the
>   mounted filesystem when the server does not provide ownership
>   information. It may be specified as either a username or a numeric
>   uid. When not specified, the default is uid 0. The mount.cifs helper
>   must be at version 1.10 or higher to support specifying the uid in
>   non-numeric form.
>
> **gid=arg** sets the gid that will own all files or directories on the
>   mounted filesystem when the server does not provide ownership
>   information. It may be specified as either a groupname or a numeric
>   gid. When not specified, the default is gid 0. The mount.cifs helper
>   must be at version 1.10 or higher to support specifying the gid in
>   non-numeric form.

[link to the mount.cifs man](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs)

to find your user open a terminal and run this command:

```
whoami
```

to find your group run this command: ( in this case the right group will be the first from the left )

```
groups
```

Comment: Thanks for that. When I try do this `sudo mount.cifs -o username=myuser,uid=youruser,gid=yourgroup //xxx.xxx.xx.xx/myfolder /mnt/windowsshare/` it asks for the password of the network share and then it works, but when I tried doing this `sudo mount.cifs -o username=myuser,password=mypassword,uid=youruser,gid=yourgroup //xxx.xxx.xx.xx/myfolder /mnt/windowsshare/` by adding the password, it says permission denied, not sure why? Also when how I can make this permenant so that I don't have to rewrite the command every time I lose connection or restart the computer?

Comment: hi @Tak i'm at work right now and i don't have time to help you.
i'm sorry, perhaps if you open another question someone will help you faster than me.